# "Invalid credentials" when running `jupyter notebook --no-browser` from remote server

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried everything here and nothing worked:

[Jupyter Notebook Server password invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759623/jupyter-notebook-server-password-invalid)

[How to disable password request for a Jupyter notebook session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159797/how-to-disable-password-request-for-a-jupyter-notebook-session)

When I generate a password it doesn't give me a token but when I type in the password it doesn't work.  When I copy and paste my token, it also doesn't work.

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser
[I 2022-08-04 13:37:32.069 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2022-08-04 13:37:32.069 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is ~/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 13:37:32.073 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jespinoz
[I 13:37:32.073 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.8 is running at:
[I 13:37:32.073 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=469451b2e8ec80432a0948fbbe8662347695efd8f5339307
[I 13:37:32.073 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=469451b2e8ec80432a0948fbbe8662347695efd8f5339307
[I 13:37:32.073 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:37:32.132 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/jespinoz/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3346536-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=469451b2e8ec80432a0948fbbe8662347695efd8f5339307
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=469451b2e8ec80432a0948fbbe8662347695efd8f5339307
```

[image]

This did nothing:

```
 c.NotebookApp.token = ''
 c.NotebookApp.password = u''
 c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
 c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'
```

Neither did just this:

```
c.NotebookApp.token = ''
```

Nor this:

```
jupyter notebook password
```

Nor this:

```
jupyter notebook --ip='*' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```

Comment: In case setting up Jupyter Notebook as a (local) server is not a requirement, you can use VSCode. It's [Jupyter integration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) is really well done and easy to install.

Comment: I need to run it from a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case here's what it was: I had a previous jupyter session running that I hadn't properly killed previously. I didn't realize it but I had been interacting with the zombie Jupyter server the whole time. Don't be like me: make sure there's only one server running per port - kill all your zombie python processes!

Comment: How do you do this?